# pgfplots legend order

Tags: pgfplots, bar-chart, nodes-near-coords

The following code draws a bar chart with number labels. I want the entries in the legend to be the other way around i.e. for there to be a gray box at the top with the label "two", and a white box below with the label "one". How can I do that? I could well be missing something obvious. **EDIT: read on for a version using pgfplots 1.14**

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.3}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
    ybar stacked,
    symbolic x coords={A,B,C},
    xtick=data,
    xticklabel style={align=center},
    nodes near coords={\pgfmathprintnumber\pgfplotspointmeta},
    nodes near coords align={vertical},
    nodes near coords align={anchor=north},%Move values in bar
    totals/.style={nodes near coords align={anchor=south}},
]
  \addplot [fill=white] coordinates {
({A},24)
({B},16)
({C},11)}; 
\addlegendentry{one}
 \addplot [fill=lightgray,point meta=explicit] coordinates {
({A},53)[53]
({B},47)[47]
({C},33)[33]};
\addlegendentry{two}
  \addplot[totals] coordinates {
({A},0)
({B},0)
({C},0)};
\legend{one,two}
  \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**EDIT:** for anyone who comes along later, the following code gets almost the same layout as my original post, but is compatible with version 1.14 of pgfplots (see [tex.stackexchange.com/a/162389/95441](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/162389/95441.)). I've included the `reverse legend` suggestion from Jake, which solves my original problem.

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.14}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
  \pgfplotsset{
    show sum on top/.style={
          /pgfplots/scatter/@post marker code/.append code={%
              \node[
                  at={(normalized axis cs:%
                          \pgfkeysvalueof{/data point/x},%
                          \pgfkeysvalueof{/data point/y})%
                  },
                  anchor=south,
              ]
              {\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfkeysvalueof{/data point/y}}};
          },
      },
  }
  \begin{axis}[
    reverse legend,
    ybar stacked,
    ymin=0,
    ymax=90,
    symbolic x coords={A,B,C},
    xtick=data,
    xticklabel style={align=center},
    nodes near coords={\pgfmathprintnumber\pgfplotspointmeta},
   ]
   \addplot [fill=white] coordinates {
      ({A},24)
      ({B},16)
      ({C},11)};
   \addlegendentry{one}
   \addplot [fill=lightgray,show sum on top] coordinates {
      ({A},53)
      ({B},47)
      ({C},33)};
   \addlegendentry{two}
   \legend{one,two}
  \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Maybe you should have noticed that you adapted your solution from (most probably) http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/162389/95441.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by "should have noticed". I did make use of the answer you have given the link to, and (if I remember correctly) upvoted it by way of thanks. I have added a link to it in my post.

Comment: Yes, something like your last edit is fine. The reason why this helps is, that *you* didn't write *why* this is working and also at the link are given other useful information like that `normalized axis cs:` isn't documented so far. That was the reason why I was searching for that and found that link. Thanks for editing the question!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Set `reverse legend` in the `axis options`, and add `forget plot` to those `\addplot` commands you don't want to appear in the legend. Also, you only need either the two `\addlegendentry` commands, or the `\legend` command, but not both.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.3}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
    ybar stacked,
    reverse legend,
    symbolic x coords={A,B,C},
    xtick=data,
    xticklabel style={align=center},
    nodes near coords={\pgfmathprintnumber\pgfplotspointmeta},
    nodes near coords align={vertical},
    nodes near coords align={anchor=north},%Move values in bar
    totals/.style={nodes near coords align={anchor=south}},
]
  \addplot [fill=white] coordinates {
({A},24)
({B},16)
({C},11)}; 
\addlegendentry{one}
 \addplot [fill=lightgray,point meta=explicit] coordinates {
({A},53)[53]
({B},47)[47]
({C},33)[33]};
\addlegendentry{two}
  \addplot[totals, forget plot] coordinates {
({A},0)
({B},0)
({C},0)};
  \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

As Jake already stated in [his answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/339495/95441) the alternative would be to use the `\legend` command. This has the advantage that do don't need to use `forget plot` on the `\addplot` command, which besides not adding the plot to the legend has some other (maybe/sometimes unwanted) "side effects" like not advancing the `cycle list`.

To ignore `\addplot`s with the `\legend` command, just write empty labels for them.

(By the way: When both, i.e. `\addlegendentry` and `\legend`, are given, `\legend` "wins".)

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
    \pgfplotsset{compat=1.3}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            ybar stacked,
            reverse legend,
            symbolic x coords={A,B,C},
            xtick=data,
            nodes near coords,
            nodes near coords align={anchor=north},%Move values in bar
            totals/.style={
                nodes near coords align={anchor=south},
                red,        % <-- added, to distinguish it from "one"
            },
        ]
            \addplot [fill=white] coordinates {
                (A,24) (B,16) (C,11)
            };
            \addplot [fill=lightgray,point meta=explicit] coordinates {
                (A,53)[53] (B,47)[47] (C,33)[33]
            };
            \addplot [totals] coordinates {
                (A,0) (B,0) (C,0)
            };
            % give all the `\addplot's that should not be shown in the legend
            % an empty legend entry
            % (here "three" is empty, because there is a comma after the last entry)
            \legend{
                one,
                two,
            }
%            % perhaps this one easier to understand
%            % (here "two" isn't shown in the legend
%            \legend{
%                one,
%                ,
%                three
%            }
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: image showing the result of above code]