# Add rows for sum/mean/std at end of pgfplotstable

Tags: pgfplotstable

How do you add a one or multiple rows at the bottom of a table in pgfplotstable that is a summation/average/variance or other function of the above data in that particular column?

How can this be done for just some of the columns in a table?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This answer is heavily inspired from [Create a contingency table using pgfplotstable](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/62409/create-a-contingency-table-using-pgfplotstablex) (I even stole the example table).  For the second part (only treat some columns) it borrows from [How to mark/label nth data point from file in pgfplots?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/191365/how-to-mark-label-nth-data-point-from-file-in-pgfplots).

The basic idea is: It is relatively easy to add columns to a table with entries computed from other columns, but it is not possible to add rows.  Thus, we transpose, then add columns, then we transpose again.  Since selecting a subset of the columns may not be what everyone needs, the below solution contains a macro `\addstatistics` that adds sum, mean and standard deviation for all columns as well as a macro `\addsomestatistics` that accepts as a third argument a list of columns (numbers between 0 and the number of data columns minus one in the tikz `foreach` list format).  The first two arguments in both cases are the table and the name of the label column.  See the code for examples how to use it.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}

\newcommand{\addstatistics}[2]{ %
% #1=table name
% #2=first column name
% Transpose the table, so we can work on rows instead of columns
\pgfplotstabletranspose[colnames from={#2},input colnames to={#2}]{\intermediatetable}{#1}
%
% Sums for each column
\pgfplotstablecreatecol[
    create col/assign/.code={%
        \def\colsum{0}
        \pgfmathtruncatemacro\maxcolindex{\pgfplotstablecols-1}
        \pgfplotsforeachungrouped \col in {1,...,\maxcolindex}{
            \pgfmathsetmacro\colsum{\colsum+\thisrowno{\col}}
        }
        \pgfkeyslet{/pgfplots/table/create col/next content}\colsum
    }
]{Sum}\intermediatetable
%
\pgfplotstablecreatecol[
    create col/expr={\thisrow{Sum}/(\pgfplotstablecols-2)}
]{Mean}\intermediatetable

% Standard deviation for each column
\pgfplotstablecreatecol[
    create col/assign/.code={%
        \def\colsumdevsquares{0}
        \pgfmathtruncatemacro\maxcolindex{\pgfplotstablecols-3}  % ignore the sum and the mean column!
        \pgfplotsforeachungrouped \col in {1,...,\maxcolindex}{
            \pgfmathsetmacro\colsumdevsquares{\colsumdevsquares+(\thisrowno{\col}-\thisrow{Mean})^2}
        }
        \pgfmathsetmacro\colstd{sqrt(\colsumdevsquares/(\maxcolindex-1))}%
        \pgfkeyslet{/pgfplots/table/create col/next content}\colstd
    }
]{Standard Deviation}\intermediatetable
%
% Transpose back to the original form
\pgfplotstabletranspose[colnames from=#2, input colnames to=#2]{\statstable}{\intermediatetable}
}
%

\newcommand{\addsomestatistics}[3]{ %
% #1=table name
% #2=first column name
% #3=list of columns to decorate
% Transpose the table, so we can work on rows instead of columns
\pgfplotstabletranspose[colnames from={#2},input colnames to={#2}]{\intermediatetable}{#1}
%
% Sums for each column
\pgfplotstablecreatecol[
    create col/assign/.code={%
      \def\entry{}
      \foreach \i in {#3} {
        \ifnum\pgfplotstablerow=\i
          \def\colsum{0}
          \pgfmathtruncatemacro\maxcolindex{\pgfplotstablecols-1}
          \pgfplotsforeachungrouped \col in {1,...,\maxcolindex}{
              \pgfmathsetmacro\colsum{\colsum+\thisrowno{\col}}
          }
          \xdef\entry{\colsum}
        \fi
      }
      \pgfkeyslet{/pgfplots/table/create col/next content}\entry
    }
]{Sum}\intermediatetable
%
\pgfplotstablecreatecol[
    create col/assign/.code={%
      \def\entry{}
      \foreach \i in {#3} {
        \ifnum\pgfplotstablerow=\i
          \pgfmathsetmacro\colmean{\thisrow{Sum}/(\pgfplotstablecols-2)}
          \xdef\entry{\colmean}
        \fi
      }
      \pgfkeyslet{/pgfplots/table/create col/next content}\entry
    }
]{Mean}\intermediatetable

% Standard deviation for each column
\pgfplotstablecreatecol[
    create col/assign/.code={%
      \def\entry{}
      \foreach \i in {#3} {
        \ifnum\pgfplotstablerow=\i
          \def\colsumdevsquares{0}
          \pgfmathtruncatemacro\maxcolindex{\pgfplotstablecols-3}  % ignore the sum and the mean column!
          \pgfplotsforeachungrouped \col in {1,...,\maxcolindex}{
            \pgfmathsetmacro\colsumdevsquares{\colsumdevsquares+(\thisrowno{\col}-\thisrow{Mean})^2}
          }
          \pgfmathsetmacro\colstd{sqrt(\colsumdevsquares/(\maxcolindex-1))}%
          \xdef\entry{\colstd}
        \fi
      }
      \pgfkeyslet{/pgfplots/table/create col/next content}\entry
    }
]{Standard Deviation}\intermediatetable
%
% Transpose back to the original form
\pgfplotstabletranspose[colnames from=#2, input colnames to=#2]{\statstable}{\intermediatetable}
}
%

\begin{document}

\pgfplotstableread{
    Gender Right-handed Left-handed Ambidextrous
    Male             43           9           10
    Female           44           4            5
    Other            20           3            3
}\chisquaredata

\addstatistics{\chisquaredata}{Gender}

\pgfplotstabletypeset[
  every head row/.style={%
    before row={\toprule 
        & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Handedness}\\
        \cmidrule{2-4}},
    after row=\midrule},
  every last row/.style={after row=\bottomrule},
  columns/Gender/.style={string type},
  columns={Gender, Right-handed, Left-handed, Ambidextrous},
]\statstable

\addsomestatistics{\chisquaredata}{Gender}{0,2}

\pgfplotstabletypeset[
  every head row/.style={%
    before row={\toprule 
        & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Handedness}\\
        \cmidrule{2-4}},
    after row=\midrule},
  every last row/.style={after row=\bottomrule},
  columns/Gender/.style={string type},
  columns={Gender, Right-handed, Left-handed, Ambidextrous},
]\statstable

\end{document}
```

[image: the two tables]

Comment: I did not expect an answer on this question. This looks perfect, thanks a lot!