# How to mark/label nth data point from file in pgfplots?

Tags: pgfplots, nodes-near-coords

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.10}

\pgfplotstableread{
0.01    1.00
0.02    2.00
0.03    3.00
0.04    4.00
0.05    5.00
}\datatable

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[ymin=0, ymax=6]
\addplot table  {\datatable}
node[pos=0.0, pin=above:"Unidentified peak"]{} % pos only allows for fractional value
node[pos=0.2, pin=above:"Bragg peak"]{} % pos only allows for fractional value
node[pos=1.0, pin=above:"my custom label"]{} % pos only allows for fractional value
;

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**UPDATE:**
A slightly shorter version of the second solution in the answer by @Matthew Leingang:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable} % For \pgfplotstableread
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.10}

\pgfplotstableread{
0.01    1.00
0.011   2.00
0.012   3.00
0.013    4.00
0.05    5.00
}\datatable
% \pgfplotstableread{results.dat}\datatable

\pgfplotstablegetrowsof{\datatable}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\N}{\pgfplotsretval}  

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[ymin=0, ymax=6]
  \addplot+[mark=none, forget plot] table {\datatable};
  \addplot+[only marks] table  {\datatable}
    % pos = (index-1)/(N-1)  (index starting from 1)
    node[pos=(1-1)/(\N-1), pin=right:first point (1/\N)]{}
    node[pos=(3-1)/(\N-1), pin=-45:third point (3/\N)]{}
    node[pos=(4-1)/(\N-1), pin=-45:end of linear behaviour (4/\N)]{}
;
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Do you want to label just the nth point, or every nth point? For example, do you want to label just point number 2, or also points 4, 6,  8...?

Comment: just the nth point, possibly an arbitrary number of points, specified by their line number / index, e.g. (1, 2, 5).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I think the easiest way to do it is as you've done, keeping in mind that if there are *N* equally spaced points, the `pos`-ition of the *n*-th point is (n-1)/(N-1).

In your case you have 5 points and you want to mark the second, so it should be at position 0.25:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable} % For \pgfplotstableread

\pgfplotstableread{
0.01    1.00
0.02    2.00
0.03    3.00
0.04    4.00
0.05    5.00
}\datatable

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[ymin=0, ymax=6]
\addplot table  {\datatable}
node[pos=0.0, pin=right:``first point'']{} 
node[pos=0.25, pin=above:``second point'']{} 
node[pos=1.0, pin=left:``last point'']{} 
;

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: sample code output]

This will work as along as your points are evenly spaced.  If they are not, you have two choices that I know of:

1. calculate the relative position based on the point coordinates.  If they are labeled `x_1, x_2, ..., x_N`, the *n*-th point is at position `(x_n - x_1)/(x_N - x_1)`.
2. Use a plot handler that only plots the points without interpolation, e.g., `only marks`.  Then you can use fractional positions and the handler will “snap to” the point indexed by that fraction.  So if there are five points `pos=0.25` will snap to the second point regardless of whether it is really 1/4th of the way from the left to right.

If you have unevenly spaced points and you want to mark them, interpolate them, *and* label them, you can use a two-step approach.  First, plot without marks with `\addplot+[mark=none,forget plot] ...`  Then plot only marks and label with `\addplot+[only marks] ... node[pos=0.25] ...`.  Here is an example of that:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
    declare function={
        f(\x) = 2*(\x)^3 - 3*(\x)^2 - 12 *\x;
    }]
    \begin{axis}[
        width=\linewidth,
        xmin=-3.3,xmax=4,
        ymin=-21,ymax=21,
        xtick={-1,0.5,2},
        xticklabels={$-1$,$\frac12$,$2$},
        ytick=\empty,
        samples=50
    ]
        \addplot+[domain=-3:4,mark=none,forget plot] {f(x)};
        \addplot+[samples at={-1.8117,-1,0,0.5,2,3.3117},only marks] {f(x)}
            node[pos=0,
                pin={-88:$\left(\frac{1}{4}\left(3 - \sqrt{105}\right),0\right)$},
                ] {}
            node[pos=0.2,pin={$(-1,7)$}] {}
            node[pos=0.4,pin={15:$(0,0)$}] {}
            node[pos=0.6,pin={0:$\left(\frac12,-6\frac12\right)$}] {}
            node[pos=0.8,pin={90:$(2,-20)$}] {}
            node[pos=1.0,pin={95:$\left(\frac{1}{4}\left(3 + \sqrt{105}\right),0\right)$}] {}
        ;
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: second sample code output]

The `forget plot` command keeps the plot cycle from shifting so the second plot is styled exactly as the first one is.  The second `\addplot` marks specific (unevenly spaced) points.  Since there are six of them, the position of the *n*-th is `0.2n`.

Answer (score 12):

I would use the `nodes near coords` functionality for this, which allows you to associate the labels directly with the coordinates, regardless of the spacing. With a bit of TikZ style acrobatics, you can define a key

```
nodes near some coords={1,3}
```

that takes either a single coordinate index or a list of indices, and activates the label printing only for those coordinates:

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable} % For \pgfplotstableread
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.10}

\pgfplotsset{
    node near coord/.style={ % Style for activating the label for a single coordinate
        nodes near coords*={
            \ifnum\coordindex=#1\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfplotspointmeta}\fi
        }
    },
    nodes near some coords/.style={ % Style for activating the label for a list of coordinates
        scatter/@pre marker code/.code={},% Reset the default scatter style, so we don't get coloured markers
        scatter/@post marker code/.code={},% 
        node near coord/.list={#1} % Run "node near coord" once for every element in the list
    }
}

\pgfplotstableread{
0.01    1.00
0.02    2.00
0.024    3.00
0.04    4.00
0.05    5.00
}\datatable

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[ymin=0, ymax=6, every node near coord/.style=above left]
\addplot +[
    nodes near some coords=0
] table {\datatable};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

---

The same approach can also be used to supply the label to be printed for each coordinate, and the desired alignment.

Calling

```
\addplot +[
    nodes near some coords={1/Bragg valley/below,3/Bragg peak/above}
] table {\datatable};
```

will yield the following:

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable} % For \pgfplotstableread

\pgfplotsset{
    node near coord/.style args={#1/#2/#3}{% Style for activating the label for a single coordinate
        nodes near coords*={
            \ifnum\coordindex=#1 #2\fi
        },
        scatter/@pre marker code/.append code={
            \ifnum\coordindex=#1 \pgfplotsset{every node near coord/.append style=#3}\fi
        }
    },
    nodes near some coords/.style={ % Style for activating the label for a list of coordinates
        scatter/@pre marker code/.code={},% Reset the default scatter style, so we don't get coloured markers
        scatter/@post marker code/.code={},% 
        node near coord/.list={#1} % Run "node near coord" once for every element in the list
    }
}

\pgfplotstableread{
0.01    3.00
0.02    2.00
0.024    3.00
0.04    4.00
0.05    1.00
}\datatable

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[ymin=0, ymax=6, every node near coord/.style=above left]
\addplot +[
    nodes near some coords={1/Bragg valley/below,3/Bragg peak/above}
] table {\datatable};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

---

If you want to use `pin`s, you can use a slightly altered (and slightly more elegant) version of the approach:

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable} % For \pgfplotstableread

\pgfplotsset{
    pin near coord/.style args={#1/#2}{% Style for activating the label for a single coordinate
        scatter/@pre marker code/.append code={
            \ifnum\coordindex=#1 \node[pin=#2]{};\fi
        }
    },
    pins near some coords/.style={ % Style for activating the label for a list of coordinates
        scatter,
        scatter/@pre marker code/.code={},% Reset the default scatter style, so we don't get coloured markers
        scatter/@post marker code/.code={},% 
        pin near coord/.list={#1} % Run "pin near coord" once for every element in the list
    }
}

\pgfplotstableread{
0.01    3.00
0.02    2.00
0.024    3.00
0.04    4.00
0.05    1.00
}\datatable

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[ymin=0, ymax=6, every node near coord/.style=above left]
\addplot +[
    pins near some coords={1/south:Bragg valley,3/Bragg peak}
] table {\datatable};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `node near coord` is something I should learn more about.  Would there be a way to specify the point meta in the table and display it automagically?

Comment: I'd like to use a custom label text, not the index or the value. Is this also possible with `node near coord`?

Comment: @Hotschke: Is the label text different for each data point? If yes, how do you want to specify it: in an extra column in the table, or in the list of coordinates?

Comment: @MatthewLeingang: Yes, that's possible. You can add a column to the table that contains the meta value or text, and then use `\addplot table [meta index=<column number>] ...`, for instance.

Comment: In the list of coordinates. I'd prefer not to touch the input data file. A label could be "Bragg peak".

Comment: @Hotschke: I've edited my answer.

Comment: @Jake: This is exactly as I was looking for. Thank you.

Comment: Now I am getting greedy. Is it also possible to use the 'pin' label style?

Comment: @Hotschke: It is. See the edit.

Comment: @Jake: I've accepted the answer by Matthew Leingang because it does not require too much setup. What do you consider as an advantage of your approach?

Comment: @Hotschke: Quite obviously the more compact "user side" code. The "setup" is limited to the one `\pgfplotsset` block.

Comment: @Jake: Can I rotate a subset of pins with your approach? In other words, do I have full functionality of the standard pin syntax?

Comment: Coming back to this solution after a  few years...I prefer labels to pins but you can just search and replace `pin` with `label` and it all works fine.  For more advanced labels I had to replace `\node[pin=#2]` with `\node[pin={#2}]` but other than that it seems to work great.