# Arrow tip center with TikZ (and pgfplots)

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

The arrow default behaviour is shown on the left picture part. How can I achieve that the “circle” arrow tips (see the picture below) end at their center, as drawn in the right image, but without manual tweaking?

If it is important: I need it to mark beginning and end of a curve in pgfplots, but I missed this feature so many times in TikZ as well that I post the more general question.

[image: Arrow behaviour: state of the art and what I need.]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm,convert]{standalone}

\usetikzlibrary{arrows}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw [black!20] (-.2,-.2) grid (1.2,1.2);
\draw [<->] (0,0) -- (1,1);
\draw [o-*] (0,1) -- (1,0);
\begin{scope}[xshift=1.5cm]
  \draw [black!20] (-.2,-.2) grid (1.2,1.2);
  \draw [<->] (0,0) -- (1,1);
  \draw [o-*] (-.06,1.06) -- (1.06,-.06);
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

---

Ignasi posted a solution that works with pgfplots as well (thanks for that) but it does not integrate in the arrows “system” and lengths have to be given manually. Is there a solution that provides these features?

---

Using the solution with pgfplots results in strange looking graphs if there are
plot coordinates inside the arrow tip:

[image: Strange looking plot]

I consider this being a feature but a different behaviour could be beneficial. So, is there a possibility to automatically skip coordinates inside the arrow tip? Using a fill for the ring is no solution since it will remove other objects as well. Here the code for the plot:

```
\documentclass[tikz,convert]{standalone}

\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[markstart/.style={{Circle[open, length=4mm]}-,shorten <=-2mm}]
\begin{axis}[width=5cm]
\addplot [markstart] coordinates { (0,0) (0.01,0) (0.01,0.01) (0.04,0.03) (.5,.5) };
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I'm not sure about what you want to obtain.  Is it similar to `\addplot [markstart] coordinates { (0,0) };
\addplot [no marks] coordinates { (0,0) (0.01,0) (0.01,0.01) (0.04,0.03) (.5,.5) };`?

Comment: No, more `\addplot [markstart] coordinates { (0,0) (0.04,0.03) (.5,.5) };`, i. e. automatically skipping of the coordinates inside of the ring. But that's just a bonus question, I added it mainly to show the picture as mentioned in the comment to your answer. The suggestion in your comment could as well be achieved by `... node [...,pos=0] {}`, or am I wrong about that?

Comment: I've updated my answer. Look if it helps.

Answer (score 6):

If new (`TiKZ 3.0`) `arrows.meta` library is used, `tip` length can be fixed and with `shorten` help, arrows circle centers can be moved to point where you want:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm,convert]{standalone}

\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw [black!20] (-.2,-.2) grid (1.2,1.2);
\draw [<->] (0,0) -- (1,1);
\draw [{Circle[open]}-{Circle}] (0,1) -- (1,0);
\begin{scope}[xshift=1.5cm]
  \draw [black!20] (-.2,-.2) grid (1.2,1.2);
  \draw [<->] (0,0) -- (1,1);
  \draw [{Circle[open, length=1mm]}-{Circle[length=2mm]}, shorten >=-1mm, shorten <=-.5mm] (0,1) -- (1,0);
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I supose there exists some variable which defines tip length and can be used to automatically compute `shorten` length, but I don't know it.

**Update**

If just want to mark start and ending point in a `pgfplots` curve, instead of `tips` and `arrows` can use `pgfplots mark` or just `circle` nodes as you said in your comments or is used in [How to mark/label nth data point from file in pgfplots?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/191365/how-to-mark-label-nth-data-point-from-file-in-pgfplots/191398#191398)

Unless you `fill` circle or marks internal lines will be shown (as in next figure). If you know how many coordinates are used to draw the curve, you can use `mark repeat` to draw a curve with marks just at start and end points.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm,convert]{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[markstart/.style={{Circle[open, length=4mm] .}-,shorten <=-2mm}]
\begin{axis}[width=5cm]
\addplot [mark=none] coordinates { (0,0) (0.01,0) (0.01,0.01) (0.04,0.03) (.5,.5) } node[circle, minimum size=2pt,inner sep=0pt,draw,pos=0]{} node[circle, minimum size=2pt,inner sep=0pt,draw,pos=1]{};

\addplot [mark=o, mark repeat=4] coordinates { (0,0.4) (0.01,0.39) (0.01,0.35) (0.04,0.32) (.5,.0) };
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that works even with pgfplots, albeit giving some strange looking results under special conditions (I will add an example picture to the question). Nevertheless, a solution with automatic computation would be handy, even better if it integrates into the arrows syntax.

Answer (score 5):

While this does not **exactly** answer your question, it does provide a way of getting the circles (filled or not) where you want them **without** having to tweak things.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm,convert]{standalone}

\usetikzlibrary{arrows}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw [black!20] (-.2,-.2) grid (1.2,1.2);

  \node[circle,inner sep=1pt,draw] (A) at (0,1) {};
  \node[circle,inner sep=1pt,draw,fill] (B) at (1,0) {};
  \draw (A) -- (B);

\draw [<->] (0,0) -- (1,1);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

You can tidy this up a bit by defining styles for the end nodes and even defining a macro to accomplish this as in:

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, that's what I do for the simple cases, but it is e. g. not possible for pgfplots curves.