# How to properly center TikZ circular arrow

Tags: tikz-pgf, arrows

I want to use the `o-` arrow in TikZ to highlight certain points in a picture and assign a label to them. Here is an MWE:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node at (0,0) {+};
  \draw[o-,red] (0,0) -- (1,1) node[above] {some label};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

it produces following output:

[image: point with label - wrong]

However, I want something like this:

[image: point with label - correct]

I have achieved the correct solution by using

```
\draw[o-,red, shorten <= -2.3pt] (0,0) -- (1,1) node[above] {some label};
```

which works fine, but, however, this is not a good solution since if I change e.g. the size of the arrowhead or the line width, things break apart and I have to figure out the correct shorten value again. Plus it is not very accurate and it is cumbersome to find the correct shorten value. It would be more practical if the anchor of the `o-` arrow in Tikz is at the centre of the circle. How can I achieve that?

Comment: Please see [the answer to this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/192401/arrow-tip-center-with-tikz-and-pgfplots)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Peter Grill's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/451832/121799) is the way to go, I'd say. This here is just to show you some options, and also to mention that the `arrows` library has been superseded by `arrows.meta`.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node[outer sep=0pt] (plus) at (0,0) {+};
  \draw[{Circle[open,width=width("+"),length=width("+")]}-,red,shorten <={-1/2*width("+")}] (plus.center) -- (1,1) node[above] {some label};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: What if there is no node, but only a coordinate where I want to place the circle? like `\draw[{Circle[open]}-,red] (0,0) -- (1,1) node[above] {some label};` and I want the circle to be around coordinate (0,0).

Comment: @T.Pluess If you replace `(plus.center)` by `(0,0)`, you obtain exactly the same picture.

Comment: sure. I just realized that. It was not obvious at first!

Comment: @T.Pluess I should perhaps have kept `(0,0)` but I am a fan of having not too many explicit coordinates around, so I do such things sort of subconsciously. ;-)

Answer (score 5):

One way would be to *not* use the `o-` arrow style and draw the circle with the when you create the `\node`:

```
\node [circle, draw=red, inner sep=-1pt] (Plus Sign) at (0,0) {+}
```

Here, I have named this node `(Plus Sign)` so that we can draw the line to this node without having to respecify the coordinate:

```
\draw[-,red] (Plus Sign) -- (1,1) node[above] {some label};
```

[image]

Alternatively you could use a `pin`:

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass[border=1pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node [circle, draw=red, inner sep=-1pt] (Plus Sign) at (0,0) {+};
  \draw[-,red] (Plus Sign) -- (1,1) node[above] {some label};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

### Code: `pin`

```
\documentclass[border=1pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node  (Plus Sign) at (0,0) {+};
  \node [circle, draw=red, inner sep=1pt, pin={[pin edge={red, thin}, pin distance=1.4cm, pin position=45, text=red] {some label}}] at (Plus Sign)  {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: sure, but the plus sign was just an example. Often, I don't have a specific node, but some arbitrary coordinates where I want to put a label.

Comment: @T.Pluess: IN that case, I think perhaps you should use a `pin` instead of an arrow.