# pgftables: nodes near coords align depending on value?

Tags: pgfplots, nodes-near-coords

The following code results in node labels overlapping the graph. How can I align them depending on the graph so that '1375' und '1574' are below the node and the others still above?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
nodes near coords,
point meta=explicit,
nodes near coords align={auto}
]
\pgfplotstableread{
a  d
1   1557
2   1375
3   1722
4   1763
5   1574
6   1591
7   1563
}\datatable
\addplot table[y = d, meta=d] from \datatable ;
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Possible related  -- http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/191439/34618.