# Gap between line and point in pgfplots, like pointintervalbox in gnuplot

Tags: pgfplots

I wondered if it is possible to create a scatter plot in pgfplots with a similar style as the "pointintervalbox" option in gnuplot, i.e. a plot with points and lines, but there is a gap between the lines and the points.

Here is an [example](http://www.gnuplotting.org/tag/linespoints/):

[image]

Maybe something like this already exists but I couldn't find it because I don't really know how to describe it.

Thank you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In principle, you can use the `mesh` style for this: for line plots, this results in the line being drawn with individual segments, instead of using one continuous path. Then you can apply the `shorten <=1mm, shorten >=1mm` options to offset the start and end of the segments.

[image]

However, there's one implementation detail that hinders this: currently, PGFPlots uses `\pgfusepathqstroke` to draw the segments, which ignores all options like arrow tips or shortenings. So to make this work, we have to redefine an internal macro to instead use `\pgfusepath{stroke}`. Here's a key that takes care of that, and takes an optional argument for setting the gap length:

```
\makeatletter
\pgfplotsset{
    discontinuous line/.code={
        \pgfkeysalso{mesh, shorten <=#1, shorten >=#1,
        legend image code/.code={
        \draw [##1, shorten <=0cm] (0cm,0cm) -- (0.3cm,0cm);
        \draw [only marks] plot coordinates {(0.3cm,0cm)};
        \draw [##1, shorten >=0cm] (0.3cm,0cm) -- (0.6cm,0cm);
        }}
        \def\pgfplotsplothandlermesh@VISUALIZE@std@fill@andor@stroke{%
            \pgfplotspatchclass{\pgfplotsplothandlermesh@patchclass}{fill path}%
            \pgfplotsplothandlermesh@definecolor
            \pgfusepath{stroke}
            \pgfplotsplothandlermesh@show@normals@if@configured
        }%
    },
    discontinuous line/.default=1.5mm
}
\makeatother
```

Putting that code snippet in your preamble, after `\usepackage{pgfplots}`, allows you to get a discontinous line like this:

```
\begin{axis}
\addplot [discontinuous line, black, mark=*] table {
0 5
1 3
2 4
3 8
4 0
};

\addplot [discontinuous line=3mm, red, mark=*] table {
0 1
2 5.5
3 7.25
4 8
};
\end{axis}
```

---

Full code:

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\makeatletter
\pgfplotsset{
    discontinuous line/.code={
        \pgfkeysalso{mesh, shorten <=#1, shorten >=#1,
        legend image code/.code={
        \draw [##1, shorten <=0cm] (0cm,0cm) -- (0.3cm,0cm);
        \draw [only marks] plot coordinates {(0.3cm,0cm)};
        \draw [##1, shorten >=0cm] (0.3cm,0cm) -- (0.6cm,0cm);
        }}
        \def\pgfplotsplothandlermesh@VISUALIZE@std@fill@andor@stroke{%
            \pgfplotspatchclass{\pgfplotsplothandlermesh@patchclass}{fill path}%
            \pgfplotsplothandlermesh@definecolor
            \pgfusepath{stroke}
            \pgfplotsplothandlermesh@show@normals@if@configured
        }%
    },
    discontinuous line/.default=1.5mm
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{axis}[
    axis background/.style={
        shade,bottom color=gray!50,top color=white
    }
]
\addplot [discontinuous line, black, mark=*] table {
0 5
1 3
2 4
3 8
4 0
};

\addplot [discontinuous line=3mm, red, mark=*] table {
0 1
2 5.5
3 7.25
4 8
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Haha, nice!! I was hoping that noone will go through this :P But for large sample sizes in other plots, you just earned another long coffee break. That really makes a difference.

Comment: @percusse: You're absolutely right. I've edited my answer to use a key instead, which makes it easier to keep the change local, so "real" `mesh` plots aren't affected and can keep using `\pgfusepathqstroke`.

Comment: @Jake: I want to add a pin to a few data points. I am drawing with your `discontinuous line` style. However, I'd like to have the pin snap to the points. See e.g. http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/191365/how-to-mark-label-nth-data-point-from-file-in-pgfplots. Do I have to add the markers a second time?

Comment: @Jake: I've noticed that using a cycle list is not working. Do I have to specify the color explicitly in the addplot command?

Comment: Another issue I have encountered is when trying to calculate intersections (e.g. http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/38572/8917). Without `discontinuous line` every thing works as expected.

Comment: My gratitude for the answer is long overdue, ever since I updated my system this code works well. Unfortunatelly I have run into difficulties with the legend, be it in the plot or at the axis labels, where I like them.

Comment: @Rainer: What kind of difficulties do you mean?

Comment: Sorry, I am having difficulties with the markup, since I want to add code and an image. I guess I have to open a new question. I will post a link here.

Comment: Okay, I opened a new question: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/280279/labels-when-using-gaps-between-line-and-point-in-pgfplots. Perhaps someone can figure it out.

Answer (score 7):

If you don't have varying background color, you can draw the markers with background color

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.10}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[]
\addplot+[mark options={very thick,draw=white},samples=5] {rand};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This solution has issues with overlapping curves (illustrated here http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/245526/plot-data-points-with-linespoints-but-lines-should-have-gaps). However, it has been pointed out that it should be faster than the answer by Jake.

Comment: @Hotschke Did you see my sentence at the top? And it was also Jake and myself who pointed that out.

Comment: Do you mean the sentence about varying background color? Yes, I saw this. However, I think the more common case are intersecting curves instead of varying background colors. I just wanted to make it more explicit. Sorry if I seem to have ignored your sentence or the comments. I didn't want to be offensive. Originally, I was looking for a gnuplot solution, but was quite surprised that the author of the gnuplot solution didn't point it out. Or maybe I am even more surprised that there is no possibility in gnuplot at all. Anyhow thanks for setting this right.

Comment: @Hotschke No problem. I just thought you missed my nickname in those comments above. Another way is to use a scatter plot then connect them artificially. Would be also slow but it is an alternative.