# Plotting a directed graph using pgfplots

Tags: pgfplots, graphs

I have a few files in the following format:

```
x   y
12  12
12  13
13  15
15  15
15  13
13  12
12  10
10  8
8   8
8   10
10  12
12  12
12  10
10  10
```

And I wanted to plot them as a directed graph in a .tex file using pgfplots.

The code I am currently using is this one

```
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[title=File1,
             xlabel={},
             ylabel={}]
\addplot table {data-1.txt};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
```

This plots the points with lines between them but it is not enough for what I need. I would like to

1. Set a different color for the first point
2. Have arrows indicating between the dots indicating the "path" the dots take.

Some files (as the one in the example) may have overlapping nodes. If your solution could handle this scenario it would save me a lot of effort.

Another thing that I would like to do would be to do a linear interpolation of the points in the D-Graph that is generated. However I am totally clueless about how I am going to do that. I know that this seems rather awkward and might even be impossible with the most common linear interpolation algorithms, but if you could lend me a hand in that I would be very grateful.

As an example of the process described above, I would like to get something similar to this:

[image: None]

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you want the result of the linear interpolation to look like. Could you maybe post a mockup of what you want the final result to look like?

Comment: Thanks for the picture. I've edited my answer to show how you can use the `linear regression` feature of PGFPlots to achieve this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A solution with PSTricks. It needs http://texnik.dante.de/tex/generic/pst-node/pst-node.tex
Run it with `xelatex`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{node.data}
12  12
12  13
13  15
15  15
15  13
13  12
12  10
10  8
8   8
8   10
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage{pst-node,pst-plot}

\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(6.5,6.5)(16,16)
  \psaxes[axesstyle=frame,ticksize=0 9cm,tickcolor=black!20,Ox=7,Oy=7](7,7)(16,16)
  \saveDataAsNodes{node.data}{N}
  \psset{radius=2.5mm,arrows=->,arrowscale=1.5,nodesep=2.7mm,linewidth=1.3pt}
  \Cnodeput[linecolor=red]{0}(N0){foo}{0}
  \multido{\iA=1+1,\iB=0+1}{\numexpr\the\psLoopIndex-1}{%
    \Cnodeput{0}(N\iA){foo}{\iA}\ncline{N\iB}{N\iA}}
  \readdata\data{node.data}
  \listplot[plotstyle=LSM,linestyle=dashed,linecolor=blue,xStart=7,xEnd=16]{\data}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The equation of the linear regression line can be plotted with `\PstDebug=1`:

[image]

The nodes are named `N0`... `N9`. Any connection with any offset between the nodes is possible.

A solution for multiple nodes which are overwritten, only the last one is printed:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{node2.data}
12  12
12  13
13  15
15  15
15  13
13  12
12  10
10  8
8   8
8   10
10  12
12  12
12  10
10  10
\end{filecontents*}
\usepackage{pst-node,pst-plot}
\def\CPut(#1)#2{\pscircle*[linecolor=white](#1){3mm}\rput(#1){#2}\pscircle(#1){3mm}}

\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(6.5,6.5)(16,16)
  \psaxes[axesstyle=frame,ticksize=0 9cm,tickcolor=black!20,Ox=7,Oy=7](7,7)(16,16)
  \saveDataAsNodes{node2.data}{N}
  \psset{radius=2.5mm,arrows=->,arrowscale=1.5,nodesep=3mm,linewidth=1.3pt}
  \multido{\iA=\the\psLoopIndex+-1,\iB=\numexpr\the\psLoopIndex-1\relax+-1}%
     {\the\psLoopIndex}{\CPut(N\iA){\iA}\ncline{N\iB}{N\iA}}
  \pscircle*[linecolor=red](N0){3mm}\rput(N0){\bf\white0}
  \readdata\data{node2.data}
  \pslistplot[linecolor=blue,linestyle=dashed,plotstyle=LSM,xStart=7,xEnd=16]{\data}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you need some information on the connection itself use (`\ncput`):

```
  \multido{\iA=\the\psLoopIndex+-1,\iB=\numexpr\the\psLoopIndex-1\relax+-1}%
     {\the\psLoopIndex}{\CPut(N\iA){\iA}\ncline{N\iB}{N\iA}\ncput*[npos=0.4]{\tiny\iB/\iA}}
```

[image]

Comment: Elegant "linear interpolation algorithm" `;)`

Comment: Very interesting and well done, but could you tweak that to avoid node overlay?

Comment: give a data set as example

Comment: Sure. I updated the example in the original question.

Comment: see my edited answer. I have no idea what do you really expect if nodes are multiple defined.

Comment: Sorry, it is irrelevant. I noticed that `liftpen=2` is permanently attached to `\psellipticarc(n)` so we cannot change it to `liftpen=0` or `liftpen=1`. See my MWE [here(click)](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/16953386#16953386).

Comment: @Herbert that solution would be perfect if instead of the last one it showed the first one! However when I run it I get lots of errors like this

MiKTeX GPL Ghostscript 9.05: Unrecoverable error, exit code 1
and this

** WARNING ** Filtering file via command -->mgs.exe -q (...) -c quit<-- failed. ** WARNING ** Image format conversion for PSTricks failed. ** WARNING ** Interpreting special command pst: (ps:) failed. ** WARNING ** >> at page="1" position="(153.919, 460.974)" (in PDF)....

It also doesn't recognize \SaveDataAsNodes.

Comment: @user1790813: I changed the order of the nodes (see answer). You have to run the example with `xelatex` and, of course, to use the latest pst-node.tex from http://texnik.dante.de/tex/generic/pst-node/  (will be available  on TeXLive/MikTeX tommorrow, hopefully

Comment: @Herbert thanks a lot for your help. Concerning technical details, I am using TeXStudio with XeLaTeX from MiKTeX 2.9. I think the program installed automatically pst-node, but I will check and maybe try doing it by hand. Thanks a lot once again.

Comment: @user1790813: yes, but updates may take some days. Until that you can save the  current `pst-node.tex` in your documents directory and delete it later.

Comment: @Herbert I have decided to play a bit with the header and currently I am using this one

\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage{pst-node,pst-plot}
\usepackage{pst-plot}
\usepackage{pst-node}
\include{pst-node.tex}
\include{pst-node.sty}
\include{pst-node97.tex}

the "include" are the files that I have downloaded manually and placed into my project directory. I haven't downloaded the whole package. I went to the website you mention earlier and picked those files individually. Still there are many commands that XeLaTeX does not recognize.

Comment: That is not a good way. You should save _only_ the `pst-node.tex` and then using `xelatex` with my example. Your do not need other packages. However, it is easy to replace the current `pst-node.tex` with the new one. Run in a dos box `kpsewhich pst-node.tex` and it shows you the directory where the file is saved.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B82XQTkAkC3wM1Z1N3RIN1djZlE/edit?usp=sharing

@Herbert This is a screenshot of my TeXStudio session. The words in red are the ones that are not being recognized. In the right you have the pdf output of XeLaTeX. At bottom left you have a part of the many error messages. I don't know if that helps much but I don't know what else I can do.

Comment: I installed MikTeX 2.9 and TeXStudio. Edited TeXStudio to use xelatex as compiler, restart it and had success. Then I used `\usepackage[crop=off]{auto-pst-pdf}` and run `pdflatex -shell-escape <file>` which also worked successfully. However, I always addeded as optional argument for `xelatex` and `pdflatex` `-shell-escape`. Via the menu Options->Configure.  And I had the new pst-node.tex in the documents directory.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help. In the end I managed to compile the file using LaTeX and the DVI -> PS -> PDF chain.

Comment: That is fine. See also my extended answer for marking the line connections.

Answer (score 9):

Here's an approach that uses the code from [Gap between line and point in pgfplots, like pointintervalbox in gnuplot](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/194254/gap-between-line-and-point-in-pgfplots-like-pointintervalbox-in-gnuplot/194442#194442) to draw arrows between the coordinates.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots, pgfplotstable}
\makeatletter
\pgfplotsset{
    discontinuous line/.code={
        \pgfkeysalso{mesh, shorten <=#1, shorten >=#1}
        \def\pgfplotsplothandlermesh@VISUALIZE@std@fill@andor@stroke{%
            \pgfplotspatchclass{\pgfplotsplothandlermesh@patchclass}{fill path}%
            \pgfplotsplothandlermesh@definecolor
            \pgfusepath{stroke}
            \pgfplotsplothandlermesh@show@normals@if@configured
        }%
    },
    discontinuous line/.default=1.5mm
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\pgfplotstableread{
x   y
12  12
12  13
13  15
15  15
15  13
13  12
12  10
10  8
8   8
8   10
}\datatable

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    title=File1,
    width=10cm
]
\addplot [
    discontinuous line=2.5mm,
    very thick, black, -latex,
    nodes near coords=\coordindex,
    every  node near coord/.style={
        draw,
        circle,
        anchor=center,
        inner sep=1.5pt,
        color={\ifnum\coordindex=0 red\else black\fi}
    }] table {\datatable};

\addplot [ultra thick, blue] table [y={create col/linear regression={y=y}}] {\datatable};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Nice solution. Thanks! However, in some of the files there are points that overlap. Is there any way I can fix that or I will have to bear with two overlayed circles and numbers? Maybe I could only represent the points (with nothing inside) and add the numbers on top of the arrows.

Comment: @user1790813: That instantly becomes a much, much harder problem that's not easily solved using this approach. Depending on how many of these graphs you need to generate, I'd either go with a "proper" graph drawing software, or manual adjustments.

Comment: @user1790813: Concerning your edit: does that mean that your lines will never cross / the line labels would never overlap? Otherwise, you're just swapping one hard problem for another.

Comment: Yep. Didn't think about that. Maybe I will go for a more manual approach, but trying to use what I already have. Thanks.