# Plot data points with 'linespoints' but lines should have gaps

Tags: pgfplots, plot, gnuplot

I have asked following question on stackexchange regarding a gnuplot solution: [Plot data points with connecting lines but which leave gaps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30297735/plot-data-points-with-connecting-lines-but-which-leave-gaps).

The question is about using following linestyle for data plots:

[image]

Gnuplot apparently has issues by blanking-out of the underlying curves and currently there is no solution within gnuplot.

Can `pgfplots` plot in a similar way without this issue?

Comment: @Jake: yes it does look like a duplicate. I haven't see the other one. Let me check if it has no issues with overlapping curves.

Comment: @Jake the first answer has the same issue but the second one works. I am deleting this question and will add a link from my stackoverflow question to the second answer.

Comment: No need to delete the question, we can close it as a duplicate. That'll make it easier for others with the same issue to find the answer.