# How to remove small value labels from ybar chart?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I can't figure out a way to prevent small values showing in my labels. A problem that looked very similar to mine can be found in [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/59959/how-to-prevent-small-values-from-being-plotted-with-nodes-near-coords). Due to my non-existent coding skills I couldn't figure out this on my own. So here is the code I've got so far:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.10}

\definecolor{RYB1}{RGB}{128, 177, 211}
\definecolor{RYB2}{RGB}{251, 128, 114}
\definecolor{RYB3}{RGB}{190, 186, 218}
\definecolor{RYB4}{RGB}{255, 255, 179}
\definecolor{RYB5}{RGB}{141, 211, 199}
\definecolor{RYB6}{RGB}{253, 180, 98}

\pgfplotscreateplotcyclelist{ColorListBar}{
{RYB1!50!black,fill=RYB1},
{RYB2!50!black,fill=RYB2},
{RYB3!50!black,fill=RYB3},
{RYB4!50!black,fill=RYB4},
{RYB5!50!black,fill=RYB5},
{RYB6!50!black,fill=RYB6},
}

\begin{document}

    \begin{figure}[H]
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfkeys{
     /pgf/number format/precision=2, 
    /pgf/number format/fixed zerofill=true,
    /pgf/number format/fixed
}
\begin{axis}[
ybar stacked,
bar width=9mm,
nodes near coords,
enlargelimits=0.3,
legend style={at={(0.5,-0.20)},
anchor=north,legend columns=-1},
ylabel={ylabel},
symbolic x coords={A, B, C},
xtick=data,
cycle list name=ColorListBar
]
\addplot plot coordinates {(A,0.26) (B,0.32) (C,0.32)};
\addplot plot coordinates {(A,0.28) (B,0.29) (C,0.35)};
\addplot plot coordinates {(A,0.05) (B,0) (C,0.01)};
\addplot plot coordinates {(A,0.13) (B,0.17) (C,0.17)};
\addplot plot coordinates {(A,0.06) (B,0.01) (C,0.01)};
\addplot plot coordinates {(A,0.05) (B,0.07) (C,0.01)};
\legend{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

This results in a Figure that looks like this: 
[image]

I would like to remove the labels that currently have the value 0.01 and thus look very cluttered. How could this be achieved?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's actually the same question indeed but here is your version,

instead of just `nodes near coords`, you can apply a test as follows

```
nodes near coords = {%
    \pgfmathprintnumberto[fixed,assume math mode=true]{\pgfplotspointmeta}{\myval}%
    \pgfmathparse{\myval<0.05?:\myval}\pgfmathresult%
}
```

[image]

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for and the reply speed was rather impressive. A big thank you!