# pgfplots stacked bar plots with too little space for some "nodes near coords"

Tags: pgfplots, nodes-near-coords

When creating stacked bar charts with pgfplots, how can I avoid printing those (and only those) "nodes near coords" if there is too little space? The following MWE illustrates the problem:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{width=7cm,compat=1.12}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture} 
\begin{axis}[
  ybar stacked,ylabel={participants},
  symbolic x coords={tool1, tool2},
  xtick=data,x tick label style={rotate=45,anchor=east},
  nodes near coords,clip mode=individual]
\addplot+[ybar] plot coordinates {(tool1,1) (tool2,4)};
\addplot+[ybar] plot coordinates {(tool1,5) (tool2,0.2)};
\legend{never,rarely}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

There is too little space for the node "0.2", so how could I avoid printing it, but keeping all the others?

Comment: Too little space is not well-defined. If you increase the height then they fit or you change the scale then they don't fit etc. So instead of checking a lot of details, just filter them http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/196022/how-to-remove-small-value-labels-from-ybar-chart

Comment: You are right that "too little space" is not well defined. However, I don't have the luxury of increasing the height because of a limit on the number of pages. In any case, your pointer to the previous question solved my problem. Thanks.

Comment: I made a mistake with closing sorry it should be ok now.